# CakePHP 2.0: Error on loading an image with the html-helper

Tags: cakephp, html-helper, helper

I've switched to the newest Version of CakePHP, but when I was about to build up my layout, I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function image() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\propfe\app\View\Layouts\default.ctp on line 91
```

of course I've already included the helper in lib/Cake/Controller/AppController.php:

```
public $helpers = array('Session','Html','Js');
```

and although it's improbable, the error is in this line, here's no 91 of the layout:

```
<?php echo $this->html->image('aesculap.jpg'); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `$this->Html` instead of `$this->html`.

Comment: Omg, one of these annoying little things you just don't notice :D
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have the helper defined in AppController, but does your controller that is loading this view extend AppController or Controller.

Comment: It's just the index page via the PagesController, so of course it is